# How can we run only specific cukes with Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, cucumber-serenity

I do understand that cucumber itself not providing any such functionality where we can run specific few cukes from cucumber.

**Note: from cukes I meant multiple folder having different feature files**

For Example:

> Folder1:
>
> ```
>     -> one.feature 
>
>     -> two.feature
> ```
>
> Folder2:
>
> ```
>     -> three.feature 
>
>     -> four.feature
> ```
>
> Folder3:
>
> ```
>     -> five.feature 
>
>     -> six.feature
> ```

Now suppose if I like to run only Folder1 and Folder2 without specify any tag in cucumber file then how we can achieve it in cucumber

I like to execute few cukes folder not all of them and I do understand that I need to override the current functionality of cucumber for same.

I would like to know if someone already done it already, if yes please share with us.

**I also like to know how I can trigger same from maven command**

Comment: U can use the `features` option of `CucumberOptions` - @CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/first","src/test/resources/second"})

Comment: thanks @Grasshopper I will try same on Monday ...  Another thing is how I can provide same from maven commond line instead of hard code in TestRunner java class

Comment: mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--features ...........

Comment: `--features` is not a CLI argument.

Comment: @mpkorstanje Stand corrected. Any other way to pass the option?

Comment: `cucumber.option` gets parsed as if it were the CLI so `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="path/to/file.feature"`.

Comment: It's not the best syntax.

Comment: @mpkorstanje for multiple folders will this work? `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/first src/test/resources/second"`

Comment: Yes. Everything that works on the command line works with `cucumber.options`. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/options/EnvironmentOptionsParser.java#L25

Comment: Thanks both of you ... its working for me .. please put it as an answer, I will accept it @Grasshopper - your solution of cucumber tag always helps me .. thanks a lot ... mpkorstanje - Thanks for your input - mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/first src/test/resources/second" works :) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use the features option of `CucumberOptions` -

`@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/first","src/test/resources/second"})`

From the maven command-

`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/first src/test/resources/second"`